# Caling a C function from python, with an array as input to the function

Tags: python, ctypes

I am giving an array as an input to the C code.

The C code is as follows:

```
int ECG(int* ECG_sample)
{
   for (int i=0;i<sizeof(ECG_sample);i++)
   {
      ecg_wave_sample = ECG_sample[i];
      Filter_CurrentECG_sample(&ecg_wave_sample, &ecg_filterout);  
      Calculate_HeartRate(ecg_filterout,&global_HeartRate); // calculate HeartRate
      printf("%d\n",global_HeartRate);
   }
   return global_HeartRate;
}
```

I need to call this function in python. I have saved the name of the file as `ECG.c`. I used the command `cc -fPIC -shared -o ECG.so ECG.c`.

I used `ctypes` to call the c function like this

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np
so_file = "/home/yasaswini/hp2-notebooks/notebooks/Algorithm_testing_on_database/ECG.so"
ECG_sample = np.zeros(2000,dtype=np.int32)
ECG_sample = [4,5,6....6,7]
main_1 = CDLL(so_file)
print(type(main_1)) \\line8
print(main_1.ECG(ECG_sample))
```

I currently getting this error, even though both the inputs are arrays and int type.

```
ArgumentError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-231-c871feac52f7> in <module>
    2 #print(main.ECG(ECG_sample))
    3 #fun(ctypes.c_void_p(ECG_sample.ctypes.data))
    ----> 4 print(main_1.ECG(ECG_sample))

ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 1
```

I also tried `main_1(ctypes.c_void_p(ECG_sample.ctypes.data))` instead of line8. But I get this error

```
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-238-c96b4ca485d7> in <module>
    1 #while(1):
    2 #print(main.ECG(ECG_sample))
    ----> 3 main_1(ctypes.c_void_p(ECG_sample.ctypes.data))
    4 #print(main_1.ECG(ECG_sample))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ctypes'
```

Can someone help me with is?

Comment: Your error raises because you try to convert a python list to ctypes. Python list are complex objects with nontrivial conversion. I think you have to convert your list to array and make a ctype of that array.

Comment: I tried it this way. But I am getting the error `undefined symbol: ECG`                     `def foo(aqs : typing.List[int]) -> ctypes.Array:                                            array_type = ctypes.c_int64 * len(aqs)                                                           ans = array_type(*aqs)                                                                               return ans                                                                                      print(_sum.ECG(foo[3,4,6,6,9,11]))`

Comment: You're sample C function is incorrect. `sizeof(ECG_sample)` will be the size of a pointer, typically 4 or 8 bytes depending on the compiler.  The number of integers pointed to by `ECG_sample` should be passed as an additional parameter.

Comment: I did as u suggested @Mark. I changed the `foo` function to                           `def foo(aqs : typing.List[int]) -> ctypes.Array: 
    array_type = ctypes.c_int64 * len(aqs) 
    ans = array_type(*aqs) 
    ans_len = len(aqs)
    return ans,ans_len`                                                                                     and the `ECG` function to this                                                                              `int main(int * ECG_sample,int number_of_samples)`                                                I am still not able to clear the error.